# Need to card images on cards for a memory game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a memory game, still. I have 36 images and an array of 36 numbers. I am randomly having numbers picked from the array that make up the 18 numbers for the cards. I need to create the cards and I am trying to append `li`'s to a `ul` I have in the HTML.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Group 5 CSD 122 The Holodeck - Games-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Games</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "LCARSremake.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "matchingGame.css">
    <script src = "javascript/matchingGame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "recFrame">
        <header>
            <div id = "header" class = "lcars-row header">
                <div class="lcars-elbow left-bottom"></div>
                <div class="lcars-bar horizontal">
                    <div><h1 class = "title right"> Matching Game </h1></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lcars-bar horizontal right-end decorated"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id = "leftmenu" class = "lcars-column start-space lcars-u-1">
            <ul style = "list-style-type: none" class = "leftmenu">
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank1"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 home"><a href = "index.html"> Home </a></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 games"><a href = "games.html"> Games </a></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 about"><a href = "about.html"> About </a></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank2"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank3"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank4"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank5"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank6"></li>
                <li class = "lcars-u-1 blank7"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="lcars-bar lcars-u-1"></div>
        </div>
        <main>
            <div id = "contentFrame">
                <div class = "lcars-column lcars-u-5">
                    <section class = "score-panel">
                    <div id = "startGame">Start Game</div>
                        <ul class = "rank">
                            <li><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></li>
                            <li><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class = "moves">0 </span> MOVES |  TIME:                  
                        <div class = "timer"></div>
                        <div class = "restart">
                            <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <ul class = "deck">

                    </ul>
                    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
                        <div class="popup">
                            <h2>Congratulations</h2>
                            <a class="close" href=# >Ã—</a>
                            <div class="content-1">
                                Congratulations you won!
                            </div>
                            <div class="content-2">
                                <p>You made <span id=finalMove> </span> moves </p>
                                <p>in <span id=totalTime> </span> </p>
                                <p>Rating:  <span id=starRating></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <button id="play-again"onclick="playAgain()">
                                Play again</a>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer> 
            <div id = "footer" class = "lcars-row"> 
                <div class="lcars-elbow left-top"></div>
                <div class="lcars-bar horizontal both-divider bottom"></div>
                <span class = "footerContent"><p> LCARS © Michael Okuda </p></span>
                <div class="lcars-bar horizontal right-end left-divider bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code I'm trying to use to get the images to be the list item:

```
// The function init() enables the game to begin
function init() {

    // The shuffle function shuffles the objects array
    let allCards = shuffle(cardList());
    $deck.empty();

    // The game starts with no matching cards and zero moves 
    match = 0;
    moves = 0;
    $moves.text('0');

    // A for loop creates   <li> tags with the class of card for every <i> tag
    // A class of fa fa- and a name of each object from the objects=[] array
    for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
        var img = allCards[i] + '.png';
        $deck.append(('<li class="card"><img src = "images/symbols/ ' + img + '/>/li>'))
    }
    addCardListener();

    // Enables the timer to reset to 0 when the game is restarted
    resetTimer(nowTime);
    second = 0;
    $timer.text(`${second}`)
    initTime();
}
```

Using the debugger and I get to the part where it is supposed to append, I just get the content from here displayed:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: it looks interesting but I didn't get the issue or question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$deck.append(('<li class="card"><img src = "images/symbols/ ' + img + '/>/li>'))
```

should be

```
$deck.append('<li class="card"><img src="images/symbols/' + img + '" /></li>'))
```

Comment: Your answer produces invalid HTML

Comment: Where you think is invalid?

Comment: an element like `<img src = "images/symbols/ mycard.png" />` is produced, note that extra space which is invalid here before the "mycard"

Comment: You can try. if there's wrong or any error message, please tell me. Please don't think the redundant space stupid.

Comment: It is in the specification that it must be encoded http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt see section 2.4.3 ref https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html that indicates it is the same as HREF

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `$deck` is since you did not provide that so I have to somewhat guess.  Just a side note you apparently have a number of global variables, never a good idea.

This line is not producing valid HTML:

`$deck.append(('<li class="card"><img src = "images/symbols/ ' + img + '/>/li>'))`

Compare to

`$deck.append('<li class="card"><img src = "images/symbols/' + img + '"/></li>');`

Note it would be much better to create all the elements, then append them one time to the DOM instead of hitting it multiple times.

SO, assuming markup as such:

```
<ul id="deck"></ul>
```

Script such as:

```
var $deck = $('#deck');
var mycards = $('<div/>');
var li = $('<li class="card"><img /></li>');
for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
    var imgsrc = 'images/symbols/'+ allCards[i] + '.png';
    li.find('img').prop('src',imgsrc);
    mycards.append(li);
 }
 $deck.append(mycards.find('li'));
```